# SQL Agent Job error while trying to execute SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I keep getting the error "Executed as user: Domain\User. Unable to open Step output file.  The step failed." while trying to execute a SSIS package as a SQL Agent Job. The error is thrown almost instantaneously.

I have created a proxy account for executing the job & this account has read/write permissions to the folder where the package is saved.

Also, there is nothing being written to the error output file.

Thanks 
Girija

Comment: Did you add the user account as a *principal* of the proxy?

Comment: Yes I did try adding the user account as a principal of the proxy. But the moment I close the wizard, the user account is automatically being removed from the principal list. Not sure Why?

Comment: Is this user account added as a login on SQL Server?